# Не работает кнопка назад, машина состояний обновляется, но хендлеры заново не вызываются. Подскажите, как можно исправить

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(state="*", text="Назад")
async def back(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await Application.previous()


@dp.message_handler(Command("start"))
async def show_greeting(message: Message):
    text = message.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Приветствие.txt", "r").read()
    await message.answer(text, reply_markup=choice_target)
    await Application.target.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Application.target)
async def choice(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    text = call.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Недвижимость.txt", "r").read()
    await call.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=choice_country)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['target'] = call.data
    await Application.country.set()




@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Application.country)
async def choice(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    text = call.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Турция.txt", "r").read()
    await call.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=choice_time)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['country'] = call.data
    await Application.visitPlan.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Application.visitPlan)
async def choice(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    text = call.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Варианты оплаты.txt", "r").read()
    await call.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=choice_form_deal)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["visitPlan"] = call.data
    await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await Application.target.set()
```

Присваивается только первому хэндлеру, так как текущее состояние None, далее же просто идет переход на следующее состояние:

```
await Application.next()
```

Хэндлеры не вызываются заново из-за того, что Вы переходите на прошлое состояние previous, но машина не может опять пойти дальше без next

Comment: А можно как нибудь вызывать хендлер по изменению состояния машины?

Comment: Вы и так вызываете хэндлеры по изменению состояний. Просто нужно переключаться по ним через .next, а .set ставить только для первого состояния

Comment: Сделал через некст все равно не работает. Код ниже

Answer (score 0):

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(state="*", text="Назад")
async def back(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await Application.previous()


@dp.message_handler(Command("start"))
async def show_greeting(message: [Message, CallbackQuery], state=None):
    text = message.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Приветствие.txt", "r").read()
    if type(message) == Message:
        await message.answer(text, reply_markup=choice_target)
    else:
        await message.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=choice_target)

    await Application.target.set()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Application.target)
async def choice1(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    text = call.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Недвижимость.txt", "r").read()

    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Цель'] = call.data
    await Application.next()
    await call.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=choice_country)


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Application.country)
async def choice2(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    text = call.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Турция.txt", "r").read()
    await call.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=choice_time)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['Страна'] = call.data
    await Application.next()


@dp.callback_query_handler(state=Application.visitPlan)
async def choice3(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    text = call.from_user.first_name + "," + open("texts/ru/Варианты оплаты.txt", "r").read()
    await call.message.edit_text(text, reply_markup=choice_form_deal)
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["Когда посетит"] = call.data
    data = await state.get_data()
    await state.finish()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]